# facebook integration login issue canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Question:
canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)" getting this erro

i am using ios 9.2 xcode 7.2

Solution I tried out
1-- i add nsapptransport security

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
<key>facebook.com</key>
<dict>
<key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
<true/>                
<key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
<false/>
</dict>
<key>fbcdn.net</key>
<dict>
<key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
<true/>
<key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
<false/>
</dict>
<key>akamaihd.net</key>
< dict>
<key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
<true/>
<key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
<false/>
</dict>
</dict>
</dict>
```

2 -- i add lsqueryscheema

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>fbapi</string>
<string>fbapi20130214</string>
<string>fbapi20130410</string>
<string>fbapi20130702</string>
<string>fbapi20131010</string>
<string>fbapi20131219</string>    
<string>fbapi20140410</string>
<string>fbapi20140116</string>
<string>fbapi20150313</string>
<string>fbapi20150629</string>
<string>fbauth</string>
<string>fbauth2</string>
<string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
```

3--> even also try this one

```
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
```

but still error is there

Comment: try once in device ....

Comment: The error is benign. It simply means you don't have the corresponding app installed.

Comment: same error in device @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 1):

Have you missed to import FBSDKCoreKit ?

```
failed for URL: “fbauth2://” - error: “(null)”
```

From [Facebook Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9):

> This is an Xcode warning indicating the the canOpenURL: call returned false. As long as you have configured the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry in your plist as described above, you can ignore this warning

Comment: allready imported FBSDKCoreKit and also configured LSApplicationQueriesSchemes